# How can I deal with a circular column to output a loop number in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use a column whose values are circular (i.e. 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3....) to calculate and output the index number of the loop?
So for example in this simplified table...

```
num cir
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    1
5    2
6    3
7    1
8    2
9    3
```

How can I get this?

```
num cir index
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    2
5    2    2
6    3    2
7    1    3
8    2    3
9    3    3
```

Actually, a table I tried to manage is much bigger (millions of records times 160 columns), so if there are multiple solutions I'd like to hear more efficient ones... Thanks.

Comment: It looks like index is just equal to floor((num - 1) / 3) + 1, unless I am missing something?

Comment: Oops. I just complemented `num` column in order to avoid a table is made of only one column! Actually, num is not a well-ordered one. Sorry for that.

Comment: Tables aren't stored in any particular order, so if not ordered on `num` how should one determine to which group a given record belongs?  What is the wider context of the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @user2360798 . . . What do you mean by "not well ordered"?

Answer (score 3):

[Gordon Linoff is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16489661/297408): in SQL, tables indeed do not have inherent order. However, there still is a way to assign indices in your case. The only issue is, the order would be indeterminate and a 1 might be grouped together with a 2 that would not necessarily be the one that followed it (in whatever specific order that you might be expecting). That is, the end result might be like in your example:

```
num  cir  index
---  ---  -----
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    2
5    2    2
6    3    2
7    1    3
8    2    3
9    3    3
```

but it could well be e.g. this instead:

```
num  cir  index
---  ---  -----
7    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    2
8    2    2
6    3    2
1    1    3
5    2    3
9    3    3
```

if the `num` is not "well-ordered", as you put it (and therefore, I'm assuming, cannot be used for sorting).

The idea is to sort the dataset on the `cir` column only

```
num  cir
---  ---
1    1
4    1
7    1
2    2
5    2
8    2
3    3
6    3
9    3
```

and then use variable assignment to generate the `index` values

```
num  cir                index
---  ---                -----
1    1    1             1
4    1    2             2
7    1    3             3
2    2       1     ->   1
5    2       2          2
8    2       3          3
3    3          1       1
6    3          2       2
9    3          3       3
```

Here's how:

```
SELECT
  num,
  cir,
  `index`
FROM (
  SELECT
    num,
    @index := @index * (cir = @lastcir) + 1 AS `index`,
    @lastcir := cir AS cir
  FROM
    yourtable,
    (SELECT @index := 0, @lastcir := 0) v
  ORDER BY
    cir
) s
ORDER BY
  `index`,
  cir
;
```

As can be guessed, this expression

```
@index := @index * (cir = @lastcir) + 1
```

is the one that assigns the indices. Basically, if you remove the `* (cir = @lastcir)` part, you'll get

```
@index := @index + 1
```

which probably doesn't require an explanation: it simply increments the `@index` value.

That additional bit is there to reset the enumeration every time a new `cir` value is encountered (remember, the dataset is ordered on `cir`). In MySQL, a boolean expression, like `cir = @lastcir`, is implicitly converted to a number in a context where a number is expected, like the context of an arithmetic expression. More specifically, it is converted to `1` for `true` and to `0` for `false`. Thus, as long as `cir` is equal to `@lastcir` (i.e. the previous row's `cir`), the `index` expression is essentially equivalent to `@index := @index + 1`, but when `cir` and `@lastcir` differ (which means we've just come across a new `cir` group), the expression becomes in fact `@index := 0 + 1`, i.e. the enumeration is now started afresh.

If you like, you can test this solution [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43ee8/2).

Comment: +1 . . . You do a very good job of clarifying the issue with the ordering.  I hate the assumption that tables are ordered, because it seems to work in practice on small data sets.  But it can fail miserably on parallel machines and on data that has inserts and deletes.

Comment: Thanks. I still have to spend some more time on learning on your code, so I just tried to run it at this time, but it worked as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `num1` is ordered (although there can be gaps), one way to solve this problem is to assign the index based on the number of times the loop number has been found for smaller values of `num`.  I think the clearest way to do this in MySQL is with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.cir = t.cir and t2.num <= t.num
       ) as `index`
from t
```

If `num` is not ordered, then you have a problem.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so there is no concept of "before" and "after" for a given row.  That is, there isn't a robust way to assign index unless you have some way of ordering the results.

Comment: Apparently `num` is not well ordered (with respect to this loop number, one imagines).

Comment: @eggyal . . . I took that comment to mean that the formula `floor((num - 1) / 3) + 1)` doesn't work.  The OP should clarify.

Comment: Sorry for lots of confusion, but forget about `num` completely. Actually, what I'm trying to handle is baseball's batting lineup. So `cir` ranges from 1 to 9, and I want each time through the order represents `index`, usually ranging from 1 to 5. The only column that I can use to show `index` is `cir`. And what is OP you said above?

Comment: @user2360798: OP = *original poster* (or, depending on the context, *original post*).

Answer (score 0):

Try this self-join with non-next cirsakes and count of them:

```
SELECT t1.num AS num, t1.cir AS cir, COUNT(*) AS index
  FROM t AS t1 JOIN t AS t2 on t2.cir = t1.cir AND t2.num <= t1.num
  GROUP BY t1.num, t1.cir
;
```

Comment: Note that the OP said that the table contains "millions" of records - your resultset will therefore contain *trillions* (10^12) of records (aggregated into millions of rows).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  num,
  cir,
  @row_num := IF(@prev_cir<cir,@row_num,@row_num+1) as cir_index,
  @prev_cir:= cir
FROM 
(SELECT @row_num := 0) r
JOIN (
    SELECT 
      num, 
      cir 
    FROM 
      mytable 
    ORDER BY
      num
) t
```

First, I make sure that the records are ordered by `num`. Then I chk if the previous `cir` with the current one. If the previous `cir` is greater than the current one, I increment the `cir_index`

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a65c/6)